# Build fail while Uploading dSYMs to Crittercism automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build-automation, crittercism

As I have followed step in the document "http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Uploading-dSYMs-to-Crittercism-automatically/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle"
The demo example with  crittercismSDK is work proper, this upload build automatically.

Step-0 : Download latest build on server with version 5.1.3

Step-1 : Added SDK into application. App build with SDK. This report crash while occur on device and simulator.

Step-2 : Setting added for "Strip"

Step-3 : Change mode of file

Step-4 : Application keys and setting

Step-5 : Script added in the "Run script"

Step-6 : Build application, This fail with error, error mentioned below.

```
Uploading dSYM to Crittercism
Product Name: Application
Version: File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: Application/res/other
Invalid Arguments
Build: File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: Application/res/other
Invalid Arguments
Crittercism App ID: 342352cnzdsakdas872423xxx
Crittercism API key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
dSYM location: /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cqluunaghsacosezaivmcgvlcj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Application.app.dSYM
dSYM not found: /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cqluunaghsacosezaivmcgvlcj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Application.app.dSYM
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I am using free trial account.
If any one came across such issue then please help.

Comment: Now I am able to see the dSYM file in the build, I have changed  Target ->Build Setting -> Build options -> debug information format -> **DWARF** to **DWARF with dSYM file**

Answer (score 13):

This is due dSYM file is not generated for your project at build time

Goto Target Build Settings

**Debug Information Format** to **DWARF with dSYM File**

Also make sure your run script for upload dSYM should be last in **Build Phase** because in my case script is trying to upload dSYM file that is not generated during build so let build command generate dSYM file for upload.